# commons-logging and log4j properties file

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to use log4j via commons-logging and having problems if the log4j properties file is not called log4.properties.
I get following error:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LogMePlease).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

My code is very simple:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class LogMePlease 
{
static Log l = LogFactory.getLog(LogMePlease.class);

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    l.warn("Hello World!");
}
}
```

In my class path, i have:
**commons-logging.properties** file which contains following entries

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
log4j.configuration=log4j-test.properties
```

and 
**log4j-test.properties** file

when i run this code i get

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LogMePlease).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

If I rename log4j-test.properties file to be log4j.properties - then everything works.
So, the question is how can I setup commons logging to use arbitrary name for log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 10):

The file `commons-logging.properties` is only read from commons logging while log4j will look for `log4j.configuration` in the system properties.

So you must either specify them with `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-test.properties` on the command line as a JVM option or you must call `System.setProperty()` before the first call to any logging method (which is usually pretty hard to achieve).

Note: If you can, use the XML config `log4j.xml`; it's much more simple and powerful for configuring log4j.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the protocol to the front of System property value like so: -Dlog4j.configuration=file://log4j-test.properties

Without the protocol it will look in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

[jul - commons-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124883/commons-logging-to-use-java-util-logging/25054749#25054749), it likes your situation.

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
#org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
#org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

set log4j.properties, before instance of Log.

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", "log4j.properties");
```