# Commons logging to use java.util.logging

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging

I am trying to use commons logging and want to use java.util.logging as underlying mechanism.

**LogTest.java**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.*;

public class LogTest { 

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file","log.properties");
            Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LogTest.class);
            logger.trace("trace msg");
        }
}
```

I have src/main/resources/log.properties  ( I am using maven project )

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Default global logging level.
# Loggers and Handlers may override this level
.level=ALL
```

I am not able to see any output.
Please tell me how to programatically set the log.properties to leverage java logging.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a logger that implements the Log interface.  In this case, the [Jdk14Logger](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk14Logger.html).

Check out [How to use 'Apache Commons Logging' with 'Java SE Logging'?](http://javarushi.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-use-apache-commons-logging-with.html) for more details.

Except from link:

> Put "`commons-logging.properties`" file in your application's classpath.
>   The contents of this file should look like:
>           `org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger`
>   Setting this property instructs Commons-Logging to use JDK Logger
>   (i.e. Java SE Logger) as the Log implementation.

Then put `log-config.properties` in your classpath and configure accordingly.

If you decide to change impls in the future, [more loggers are available out of the box](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/package-summary.html).

Comment: This works (a simple Java project). But trying the same with a Maven project in Eclipse/STS does not. Tried putting the log configuration file (I put all the configuration inside commons-logging.properties itself) inside "src/main/resources" and "src/main/java" and root of the project, it is not being picked up. What is the classpath in this case, while using maven?

Comment: `src/main/resources` should be correct. If it's not working you need to verify your assumptions about what's being included in your classpath. You might also want to verify that everything is packaged correctly by cracking open you jar/war to ensure the file is where you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Loggers and Handlers may override this level
```

Try adding `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL` in your log.properties.

Comment: Sorry. This did not work. And my contents of src/main/resources/commons-logging.properties : org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger

Answer (score 0):

create **commons-logging.properties** in your classpath:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
```

set **java.util.logging.config.file** before you instance of Logger:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file","log.properties");
```

then the JDK logging will be **appender** all logs which used by org.apache.commons.logging.*;

example: spring, hibernate, struts etc.

Answer (score 0):

While Snekse's answer is basically correct, there is one point to correct/clarify:

1. **Correct**: commons-logging searches its property file from classpath. Thus, commons-logging.properties must be found in the classpath
2. **Not correct**: the JDK logger (JUL-logger) loads its configuration through a FileInputStream (which works on file system objects and not on classpath). See java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(). Thus, the System-Property value of "java.util.logging.config.file" must either be an absolute path or relative to the actual execution directory.