# Configure Commons Logging to use a specific Log4J properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I'm trying to configure Commons Logging to use a specific Log4J properties file by specifying the name of the file in commons-logging.properties however Log4J continues to look for a file named log4j.properties.

It appears that if the Log4J jar is in the class path then the contents of commons-logging.properties is ignored, however if I remove the jar from the class path the commons-logging.properties file is processed and quite rightly throws an error saying "User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable." so the commons-logging properties file is actually being read.

Both the Commons Logging and Log4J properties files are in the class path directory.

I've got the same problem as is described in [commons-logging and log4j properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524109/commons-logging-and-log4j-properties-file) but I don't understand the answer where it says....

> The file commons-logging.properties is only read from commons logging
>   while log4j will look for log4j.configuration in the system
>   properties.

Also it seems that this answer is contradicting the information in the Commons Logging user guide. The user guide says....

> **log4j.configuration=*log4j.properties*** Use this system property to
>   specify the name of a Log4J configuration file. If not specified, the
>   default configuration file is log4j.properties.

Even though I've specified the name of the Log4J configuration file it is still using the default.

Is it possible to specify the name of the log4j properties file (e.g. log4j-MyApp.properties) from within the commons-logging.properties file or have I misunderstood how the two components interact with each other?

Comment: Log4J doesn't know anything about Commons Logging, so you can't use commons-logging.properties to configure Log4J.